# How to identify the item passed as a parameter using LastModificationTime?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro triggered by an Outlook rule that process specific incoming email content and export relevant data to an Excel spreadsheet.
After the email is processed, I would like to change its category and move to another folder.
In the code below, the object "item" is the email that is given to the macro.

My idea is to find the original Outlook.MailItem using the LastModificationTime property as "item.LastModificationTime" and perform the operations.
It seems the code stops at the `Set myItem = myItems.Restrict(aux2).item(1)` with either "aux1" or "aux2" filters.
I dont have any error but the commands after that line are not executed.

```vb
Sub ExportToExcel(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim aux As String
    Dim aux2 As String
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
    
    '(irrelevant code that does email processing and excel spreadsheet writing...)
    
    Set myInbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("BACKUP").Items
    MsgBox (myItems.item(1).Subject) 'Runs OK
    aux = "[LastModificationTime] = """ & Format(item.LastModificationTime, "ddddd hh:nn") & """" 'just another try
    aux2 = "[LastModificationTime] = """ & item.LastModificationTime & """"
    MsgBox (aux) 'Runs OK
    MsgBox (aux2) 'Runs OK
    Set myItem = myItems.Restrict(aux2).item(1) 'Seems the code stops here with no error
    MsgBox ("Here") 'Does NOT run from here on
    MsgBox (myItem.Subject)
    myItem.Categories = "Categoria Laranja"
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("BACKUP_Processed")
    myItem.Move (myDestFolder)
    
End Sub
```

EDIT: I realized that I don't need "myItem". I could implement my tasks directly at the incoming "item".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, remove all "`on error resume next"` statements to that you can see the actual error.

Secondly, you are assuming `Restrict()` returns at least one item.

Thirdly, never use "= " with DateTime value - the condition will never will satisfied due to round-off errors. Always use a range - `([LastModificationTime] > 'value1') AND ([LastModificationTime] < 'value2')`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. The code doesnt have any "on error resume next" statements. I changed Restrict().item(1) to Restrict().GetFirst and it did not worked. I want exactly one match, so a range may fail. But I found I workaround to make my task work without searching any email, but changing direcly the incoming "item" MailItem

Comment: If you only want one match, use Items.Find instead - it will be faster.